# Eclipse RCP: Develop fragment plugin without source code of RCP and host plugin

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp

I’m trying to figure out if this scenario is possible and if so, how:

**Scenario**

I want a developer to work on an existing fragment plugin for an eclipse RCP product where he has no access to the source code of the eclipse RCP product.
During development I expect him to be able to debug his fragment plugin based on the currently running application

**Details**

Developer setup

•   A working and running version of the RCP product the fragment is built for already exists.

•   The product is already configured to accept the fragment plugin.

•   An existing version of the fragment plugin already runs correctly inside the RCP product.

•   Everything works

**Development continues**

Now the developer wants to continue to work on this fragment plugin but he has no longer access to the source code of the host plugin or the rest of the eclipse RCP product.

How can I make it possible for the developer to continue development on his fragment plugin AND being able to debug it at runtime in the running eclipse RCP product WITHOUT having access to the source of the eclipse RCP product and the Host plugin.

**SOLUTION:** Turns out eclipse remote debugging is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: You don't need the source code of anything in Eclipse to develop fragments and plugins. Not having the source just makes things harder when you don't understand how something works.

Comment: Let me formulate it different then: Is there any way that the developer can somehow attach to the running application and debug it without having the source code of the running application.

Comment: You can still run launch Eclipse in debug mode without the source, you will only be able to set breakpoints in the fragment you do have source for.